# SwiftUI: How can I restrict the tappable area of a view when presenting a modal(actually not modal) view over a main view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am developing an app based on a Tabview with three TabItems. Each TabItem is a List and I would be able to show a kind of modal view over those Lists. The problem  becomes when I can not call a Sheet as modal view because Sheets are almost full windowed. I need some kind of bottom modal view, so I create a View that I present over a List with higher ZIndex. It seems to work until you click in the tabbar and select another TabItem having deployed the "modal" view. The error is:

> [TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its
>   visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy
>   (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a
>   window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to
>   load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view
>   bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and
>   will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout
>   passes.

So, I would like as solution to restrict the tappable area to the "modal" view area. ¿Is there a way to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have some condition state depending on which you present your "modal-like" view, so depending on the same condition you can disable below TabView, like below

```
TabView {
// ... tabs content here
}.disabled(showingModal)
```

**Update:** Here is a demo of approach that I meant (tested with Xcode 11.3+)

[image]

```
struct TestTabViewModal: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0
    @State private var modalShown = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                VStack {
                    Button("Show Modal") { self.modalShown = true }
                        .padding(.top, 40)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                }.tag(0)

                Text("2").tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                }.tag(1)
            }.disabled(modalShown)

            if modalShown {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .fill(Color.yellow)
                    .frame(width: 320, height: 240)
                    .overlay(Button("CloseMe") { self.modalShown = false })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Asperi, the problem is that disabled() block the entire screen, even the "modal-like" view. Thank for your aportation.

Comment: @AndoniDaSilva, I added update of demo for what I meant.

Comment: Thanks Asperi, now I put the "modal-like" view out of the TabItem subview and it is now working fine.